# How do I unlock characters?

Tags: mario-tennis-aces

I have played through a significant amount of Adventure mode, I've racked up over 6500 points in online tournaments, and I still have a bunch of question marks on the character screen that I don't know what I can do about. How do I unlock characters in this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move your cursor over those question marks, the unlock condition will be displayed where the character normally would.

[image: Screenshot]

The three question marks require that you participate in an online tournament held in:

- July 2018
- August 2018
- September 2018

respectively.

If you don't participate in those tournaments, the character will be unlocked the following month.<sup>[1]</sup> By October 2018, you should've unlocked all character even without participating in any tournaments.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Source: Mario Tennis Aces News on Nintendo Switch.